# Using combobox to select records defaults to blank, but shows first record data in all other fields

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have an access database form which uses a combobox linked to a table to allow the user to select which record they would like to view. Upon opening the form, the combobox is blank, but all other fields show information pertaining to the first record. I can't figure out a way to get these to default as blank.

I'm using a foreign key.

Comment: You need to set the default record source of the form to something that doesn't return any records. E.g. `SELECT * FROM myQuery WHERE 1=0`

Comment: Hey Andre, so if I'm understanding this, "myQuery" is the table, right? What is the 1=0 doing? I've tried this but then it doesn't return any records.

Answer (score 1):

Use an SQL statement as form RecordSource that will cause form to open with an empty recordset. Fields won't show any data nor will they show #Name? error.

Include a WHERE clause with a condition that is never true:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=0;`

Then code modifies the form RecordSource after combobox selection.

`Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = " & Me.comboboxname`

Another approach is to set Recordsource to unfiltered table or query or SQL statement and also set Filter property to `ID=0` or `1=0` and FilterOnLoad to True. Then code changes Filter property after combobox selection.

`Me.Filter = "ID=" & Me.comboboxname`

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to access. So, are you saying that I would put the "Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = " & Me.comboboxname" code in On Current event?

Comment: No, combobox AfterUpdate event.